# Canon Digital Photo Professional 4.0 won't "transfer to photoshop"

Tags: windows-7, adobe-photoshop

After editing a raw image in DPP, I am not able to use the "transfer to photoshop" option. All I get is, failed to start photoshop. I am running windows 7 ultimate and PS CS5.1, and Canon DPP 4.0 64bit.

After doing several hours of research on the internet, it appears I need to change something in the registry.  If I do, what are the risks of screwing up...is there a safe way to backup the registry?

Thanks
Sue

Here are the instructions

1. Open the windows registery by using the "regedit" program (Click Start and in the text box type "regedit").
2. If the following branch doesn't exist in your registery, create it : [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Adobe\Photoshop\12.0]
3. Inside the "12.0" branch, create a string value named "ApplicationPath" and give it as value the path of Photsoshop 64 bits (C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6 (64 Bit)). You can do this by right clicking on "12.0" section and then choose New -> String Value
4. Inside the "12.0" branch, create a string value named "PluginPath" and give it as value the path of Photsoshop 64 bits plugin folder (C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6 (64 Bit)\Plug-Ins).
5. Close regedit.
6. Restart DPP and try the keystroke of ALT-P

Answer (score 0):

Even though modifying the registry is risky, you can always backup any entry. For that: Open regedit (win + r type regedit in it), search for the registry entry to be edited and at the folder icon, right click then look for "export", if something goes wrong you can always import it again by just double clicking the new file.